# Retrieve document with fields' value changed using another query

Tags: mongodb

I have this database on MongoDB for my country with data of OpenStreetMap, I imported it with [Node-Mongosm](http://sammerry.github.io/node-mongosm/) and produces three collections: `nodes`, `ways` and `relations`.

When requesting a Way, the following document is output (from mongo shell):

```
{
   "_id":492464922,
   "tags":{
      "maxspeed":"20",
      "surface":"asphalt",
      "highway":"residential",
      "oneway":"yes",
      "name":"Avenida 1"
   },
   "loc":{
      "type":"Polygon",
      "coordinates":[

      ],
      "nodes":[
         445848963,
         4844871065,
         432568566
      ]
   }
}
```

The field `coordinates` is empty for reasons unknown to me (not sure if this is a feature or a bug from `Node-Mongosm`), but I can populate it retrieving the coordinates of each node from the `nodes` field, i.e.: node `445848963`:

```
{
   "_id":445848963,
   "loc":{
      "type":"Point",
      "coordinates":[
         -83.5047254,
         10.0984515
      ]
   }
}
```

**So, my question** is if it is possible and how should I write the query for gathering a document from `ways` collection with the field `coordinates` populated with the nodes' (`ways.loc.nodes` field) coordinates *on the fly* so the retrieved document looks like this:

```
{
   "_id":492464922,
   "tags":{
      "maxspeed":"20",
      "surface":"asphalt",
      "highway":"residential",
      "oneway":"yes",
      "name":"Avenida 1"
   },
   "loc":{
      "type":"Polygon",
      "coordinates":[
         -83.5047254,
         10.0984515,
         -83.5052237,
         10.0987132,
         -83.5056339,
         10.0989286
      ],
      "nodes":[
         445848963,
         4844871065,
         432568566
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with aggregate pipeline

```
db.ways.aggregate(
[
    {$lookup : {
        from : "coords",
        localField : "loc.nodes",
        foreignField : "_id",
        as : "loc.coordinates"
    }},
    {$addFields : {
            "loc.coordinates" : {
                $reduce : {
                  input : "$loc.coordinates.loc.coordinates", 
                  initialValue :[], 
                  in : { $concatArrays : ["$$this", "$$value"] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
).pretty()
```

result

```
{
    "_id" : 492464922,
    "tags" : {
        "maxspeed" : "20",
        "surface" : "asphalt",
        "highway" : "residential",
        "oneway" : "yes",
        "name" : "Avenida 1"
    },
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Polygon",
        "coordinates" : [
            -83.5047254,
            10.0984515
        ],
        "nodes" : [
            445848963,
            4844871065,
            432568566
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: How comes you never referred the `nodes` collection to obtain the coordinates for the field `coordinates` of the `way` document in the query or you use `coords` instead of `nodes` as the name of the collection just for the explanation?

Comment: in `$lookup` from has the join collection name, i.e `coorinates` equity join by   `loc.nodes` and `coodinates._id`,  you can change it to your collection name if different